# get paramters from url without key in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'am trying to get paramter from url like that:

```
index.html#!/forum/page?1-something
```

the number that what i'am trying to get

both $location.url(); and $location.absUrl(); get the whole url

do I have to use split and how to do that?

Comment: No, what's after the `#` is the hash

Answer (score 1):

Using **$location.search()** you can get all query parameters.
by iterating an object you can get all key and value as well.

I used to iterate object using `for-in` loop. here `$location.search()` is an `object` itself so you can iterate it as:

```
for(let key in $location.search()){
   console.log("key: "+key+" value: "+$location.search()[key]);
}
```

we can also append query parameters using $location.search() by just passing parameters to it. this can be done as:

```
let obj = {site:'stack overflow', exp: 'happy coding'}
```

and this `obj` object can be passed to $location.search() as:

```
$location.search(obj);
```